# Rails one-to-many relationship method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :records
end

class Volunteering::Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :contact
end

rails console
    > Contact.last.records #NameError: uninitialized constant Contact::Record
```

If I change class Contact to has_many :volunteering_records then I get:

> Contact.last.volunteering_records # NameError: uninitialized constant Contact::VolunteeringRecord

My Volunteering::Record class has the foreign key:

> Volunteering::Record.column_names.include?('contact_id') # true

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
I figured it out. Since it's in a different namespace, the complete class name needs to be specified:

```
:has_many records, :class_name => "Volunteering::Record"
```

Comment: why `Voluntering:Record`? why not `Record` or `VolunteringRecord`?

Comment: It's been a while since I played around with namespaced models in Rails. All I can say is, unless you're got convincing need to namespace your models, avoid it like the plague! just use class Record < ActiveRecord::Base and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Change Volunteering::Record to just Record and your example should work just fine. If you're looking for an intermediary table, you want to use :has_many, :through.